# :first-child pseudo selector not targeting element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I can't get my head round why this first-child selector isn't working.

I've created a jsFiddle to show my code: http://jsfiddle.net/wDTvV/

Basically the following CSS rule isn't working:

```
.form-item-products:first-child {
  display: none;
 }
```

Does anyone know why? Have I screwed up my syntax for using pseudo selectors?

Thanks guys,

Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first child is not a `.form-item-products`, but rather `#product-guide-wrapper`, so your selector won't match.

As SLaks has mentioned, there isn't a `:first` selector in CSS like jQuery's. Given your structure, however, you should be able to use `#product-guide-wrapper + .form-item-products` instead.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work... I used #product-guide-wrapper + .form-item-products:first-child

Comment: @Rick Donohoe: Where do I say in my answer to use `:first-child`? I said the first child *is `#product-guide-wrapper`*, so you *can't* use `:first-child` on `.form-item-products`.

Answer (score 2):

`:first-child` can only match the first child element of its parent.
In your example, that's `#product-guide-wrapper`.

Unlike jQuery, CSS does not have a `:first` selector.